# mysql query with clause

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this which has values 5,10,900,1800,50,100 
These values shows

5 responses and price is 10,

900 responses and price is 1800

50 responses and price is 100

[image]

Now i want the result of these values as price sum which should display like this

[image]

Responses values should display as it is but sum of prices values should display only one at the end of responses.

I read that this could be done by using common table expressions but unfortunately mysql doesn't supports cte. and i am stuck here what other possible solutions are to this particular problem.

Comment: How you are identifying rows which ones are responses and which ones are prices ?

Comment: I don't know who is at the top of the SQL pattern, but it could have been way more simple to exploit if your database were separated in 3 tables : `RESPONSES`, `PRICE`, and `ASSIGNEMENT`. This last would be the link between a response and a price, and this table would definitevly looks like the one you want. Just a matter of well structured database.

Comment: Is it so like odd ID rows are `responses` and even id rows are `prices`?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid first value against id is responses and second one is price. whenever a entry is inserted two rows will be inserted.

Comment: @Zeratops yeah first these are two tables then the requirement is to adjust both in one table.